# FluentValidation: AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<T> results in IValidator<T> not registered

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to use FluentValidation to validate based on `object.GetType()` rather than knowing the type at compile time by injecting `IValidator<T>`, but I am getting `null` values instead of a valid validator.

Organisation + Validator

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp44
{
    internal class Organisation
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }

    internal class OrganisationValidator: AbstractValidator<Organisation>
    {
        public OrganisationValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

Console app that consumes it

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<OrganisationValidator>();
services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped(typeof(IValidatorFactory), typeof(ServiceProviderValidatorFactory)));

var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var org = new Organisation();
var validationFactory = sp.GetRequiredService<IValidatorFactory>(); // Not null
var validator = validationFactory.GetValidator(org.GetType()); // Null
validator = validationFactory.GetValidator<Organisation>(); // Null
validator = sp.GetRequiredService<IValidator<Organisation>>(); // Exception, IValidator<Organisation> not registered
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know `services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<OrganisationValidator>();` doesn't see internal classes by default. https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/di.html

You can just make OrganisationValidator public

Or, if version of your FluentValidation package is high enough (I think >=11.0) you can set parameter includeInternalTypes of AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining to true like so:
`services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<OrganisationValidator>(includeInternalTypes: true)`

Answer (score 3):

Add `using`:

```
using FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the executing assembly is diff than from the assembly your validator belongs to

Try changing this line

```
services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<OrganisationValidator>();
```

to

```
services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```